# How to set RDLC parameter that is a boolean from C#

Tags: c#, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am using the MS ReportViewer in C# to render reports.  My usage and helpers all work very well and I can generate reports and set parameters just fine... except if the parameter is typed as a non string in the RDLC

Example:  RDLC parameter IsMyFavorite is typed as Boolean.

```
parametersCollection.Add(new ReportParameter("IsMyFavorite", boolean.FalseString, false));
reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parametersCollection);
reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

inside my RDLC I use the parameter to hide a textbox my hidden expression is
=Parameters!IsMyFavorite.Value

When I render to PDF, I get an error saying I am missing a parameter...  that  is not true.  And I understand that I am passing a string into a Boolean and that it is a mismatch.  Thus, it maybe true that I am missing the parameter as a Boolean.  But using C#, how do I pass the new ReportParameter as a Boolean?

Comment: Your code is correct: which is the error message? Also note that parameter name is case-sensitive.

Comment: the parameter case is correct... I will get the error message